# Flutter-Firebase: Check if a value is is not there or false

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to check a particular document if one value is true and the other either does not exist or is false. Here is what I have

```
if (widget.challenge.individualGoalBool == true
    && widget.challenge.teamBool == null || false
)
Widget()
```

However, if the `teamBool` field does not exist or is false, this doesn't return the expected widget. If I remove it, the `true` statement works, but not the second check, so not sure what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try checking that the second one is not equal to true?

```
if (widget.challenge.individualGoalBool == true
    && widget.challenge.teamBool != true)
```

That should cover the null and false case in one expression.